# Not rendering data in lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I dont understand what is the problem here. I have to show list of about 48 countries like below but nothing is coming in UI. I have tried every possible combination but no use!

```
<aura:component implements="lightning:isUrlAddressable" access="GLOBAL">

    <aura:attribute name="countries" type="List" default="[
                                                          { Name: 'USA' },
                                                          { Name: 'India' },
                                                          { Name: 'China' }]" />

    <ol>
        <aura:iteration items="{!v.countries}" var="ctry">
            <li>{!ctry.name}</li>   
        </aura:iteration>
    </ol>

</aura:component>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because of your `ol` it's not rendering,  just replace `ol` with `ul` it works

```
 <ul>
        <aura:iteration items="{!v.countries}" var="ctry">
            <li>{!ctry.Name}</li>   
        </aura:iteration>
    </ul>
```

[image]

Comment: What's the problem with an ordered list in Aura?